# Rails virtual model

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, model, virtual

In my application I have a polymorphic `Idea` model. I want to use it with different entities like project, opportunity etc. 
In the `idea` table it is differentiated using `ideable_id` and `ideable_type`.
So as an example, for a Project `ideable_id` is the `project_id` and `ideable_type` is `Project`.
For Opportunity `ideable_id` is the `opportunity_id` and `ideable_type` is `Opportunity`

I want to create an `idea` for a model called `ideabank`. `ideabank` is a virtual model, it's not an entity like `project` or `opportunity`. How should I create such a model without a database representation which will give me `ideable_id` and `ideable_type`?
Or should I leave the fields for `ideable_id` and `ideable_type` free while adding `idea` to `ideabank`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you are using rails 3, see this
http://railscasts.com/episodes/219-active-model

`models/message.rb`

```
class Message
  include ActiveModel::Validations
  include ActiveModel::Conversion
  extend ActiveModel::Naming

  attr_accessor :name, :email, :content

  validates_presence_of :name
  validates_format_of :email, :with => /^[-a-z0-9_+\.]+\@([-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z0-9]{2,4}$/i
  validates_length_of :content, :maximum => 500

  def initialize(attributes = {})
    attributes.each do |name, value|
      send("#{name}=", value)
    end
  end

  def persisted?
    false
  end
end
```

`messages_controller.rb`

```
def create
  @message = Message.new(params[:message])
  if @message.valid?
    # TODO send message here
    flash[:notice] = "Message sent! Thank you for contacting us."
    redirect_to root_url
  else
    render :action => 'new'
  end
end
```